# : 'Cannot bind to the new value member. Parameter name: value' vb.net and how to use the values from the comboboxs

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am trying to get some items from the database into my 3rd Combobox, for the first two, there was no problem however I encountered one when trying to populate the last one. Here is the error message:

> : 'Cannot bind to the new value member.
> Parameter name: value'

Furthermore, if anyone knows how could I use the value selected from the RoomType Combobox in the RoomNumber Combobox to only display data according to the value selected in the room type. My Booking tables and Room table is linked with the BookedRooms table by their Primary keys.

```
Private Sub FrmBookings_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim connectionstring As String = "Data Source=dbNEAProject.db"
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(connectionstring),
             cmd As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM BOOKING INNER JOIN customers ON customers.customerID = booking.BCustomerID", con)
        con.Open()
        Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "booking")
        dt = ds.Tables(0)
        con.Close()
        Dim msSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM booking INNER JOIN customers ON customers.customerID = booking.BCustomerID;"
        DgvBookings.DataSource = display(msSQL, "customers")

        Dim strArray = dt.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("fname")).ToArray()
        txtBsearchFname.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        Dim MySource As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
        MySource.AddRange(strArray)
        txtBsearchFname.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MySource
        txtBsearchFname.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend



        Try
            dt = New DataTable

            con.Open()

            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT customers.fname FROM booking INNER JOIN customers ON customers.customerID = booking.BCustomerID"
            End With

            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)
            Dim r As DataRow

            txtBsearchFname.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear()
            For Each r In dt.Rows

                txtBsearchFname.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(r.Item(0).ToString)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using

    con.Close()
    da.Dispose()


    Using con1 As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr)
        Using com As New SQLiteCommand("Select CustomerID, fname FROM customers Left JOIN BOOKING ON booking.BCustomerID = customers.customerID where booking.BookingID is null", con1)
            con1.Open()

            Dim dt As New DataTable()

            dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)
            cmbCustomerData.DataSource = dt
            cmbCustomerData.DisplayMember = "fname"
            cmbCustomerData.ValueMember = "CustomerID"

        End Using
    End Using

    Using con1 As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr)
        Using com As New SQLiteCommand("Select RoomTypeName, RoomTypeID FROM RoomType INNER JOIN ROOMS ON rooms.rRoomTypeID = roomType.RoomTypeID ", con1)
            con1.Open()

            Dim dt As New DataTable()

            dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)

            cmbRoomType.DisplayMember = "RoomTypeName"
            cmbRoomType.ValueMember = "RoomTypeID"
            cmbRoomType.DataSource = dt
        End Using
    End Using

    Using con1 As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr)
        Using com As New SQLiteCommand("Select RoomNumber, RoomID FROM rooms", con1)
            con1.Open()

            Dim dt As New DataTable()

            dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)

            cmbRoomType.DisplayMember = "RoomNumber"
            cmbRoomType.ValueMember = "RoomID"
            cmbRoomType.DataSource = dt
        End Using
    End Using



End Sub
Private ConStr As String = "Data Source=dbNEAProject.db"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because You messed up order of binding data to combobox
look that

```
Using con1 As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr)
    Using com As New SQLiteCommand("Select CustomerID, fname FROM customers Left JOIN BOOKING ON booking.BCustomerID = customers.customerID where booking.BookingID is null", con1)
    con1.Open()

    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)
    cmbCustomerData.DataSource = dt
    cmbCustomerData.DisplayMember = "fname"
    cmbCustomerData.ValueMember = "CustomerID"

    End Using
End Using
```

Your first Using is fine cause You specify Datasource and then use DisplayMember. But in next one you use displaymember and specify source to data as last item. Thats why it's not working.

```
Using con1 As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr)
    Using com As New SQLiteCommand("Select RoomTypeName, RoomTypeID FROM RoomType INNER JOIN ROOMS ON rooms.rRoomTypeID = roomType.RoomTypeID ", con1)
        con1.Open()

        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)

        cmbRoomType.DisplayMember = "RoomTypeName"
        cmbRoomType.ValueMember = "RoomTypeID"
        cmbRoomType.DataSource = dt
    End Using
End Using
```

Correct order for that is:

combobox.Datasource  --> combobox.DisplayMember -->combobox.ValueMember

But then as @Jimi noted in comments - You are using same combobox in code below that. If you want to use same combobox you should clear your actual datasource by using

```
cmbRoomType.DataSource = Nothing
```

followed by

```
cmbRoomType.Items.clear()
```

and then you can use it again. But i guess it's not what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have a question if u know how to let's say the user first picks an item from the RoomType combo box which then passes the value to the Room Number combo box which would only display rooms with the same roomtype?

Comment: That's not the problem, that just a consequence: the correct sequence, when setting **a new source of data**, is `DisplayMember`, then `ValueMember` then `DataSource`. Here, the same ComboBox is set twice for no reason. Anyway, when you reset the DataSource, you first set it to `null` (`Nothing`). The main problem here is that there's no real DataBinding: the Controls are not linked to the same source of data. A BindingSource is missing...

Comment: Indeed @Jimi I have overlooked this one. You are using some combobox for different set of data

Comment: Not quite. This is the sql query that I wish to do for the RoomNumber combobox 
`Select RoomID, RoomNumber 
FROM Rooms
 INNER JOIN bookedrooms ON bookedrooms.brRoomID = rooms.RoomID INNER JOIN roomtype ON roomtype.roomtypeid = rooms.rroomtypeid
 where bookedrooms.brBookingID is null and roomtype.RoomTypeName = 'Triple';` However where the `roomtype.RoomTypeName = "Triple"` I would like to be able to use value thats been selected in the RoomType combobox. If that makes sense

Comment: Tak dokladnie o to mi chodzi tylko nie wiem jak to zrobic.

Comment: If you want to do this in the same combobox then you need to use any function that check's if user selected some Value. Be aware that doing that you need to implement something that allows user to come back to previous values in case if he made wrong choice.  
To check user selection you can use (i assume you use winform) if ComboBox.SelectedItem = not null then clear items from this comobox and populate it with another one. As event trigger you can use something like SelectedIndexChanged. Imo best option here is to use shadow comobox what is visible if user selected some value.

Comment: Czy moglbys mi pomoc jakos  zaczac ten kod?

Comment: delete our comments in polish ;) I'll post it in another answer

Answer (score 0):

So for second question
If want to do kinda nested(multipurpose?) comobobox you need to make event that changes it. This sub will run when user try to select something so it might not be "bulletproof"

```
Private Sub cmbRoomType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbRoomType.SelectedIndexChanged
 ''
    If cmbRoomType.SelectedValue = Not vbNull Then ''when user select some item <- so value is not nothing
        Dim selectedValueByUser As String = cmbRoomType.SelectedValue '' you might add that for sql query? 
        Dim selectedValueByUser2 As String = cmbRoomType.SelectedItem '' or this

        'clear dt
        cmbRoomType.DataSource = Nothing
        cmbRoomType.Items.Clear()

        Using con1 As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr)
            Using com As New SQLiteCommand("Select RoomNumber, RoomID FROM rooms", con1)
                con1.Open()

                Dim dt As New DataTable()

                dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)
                cmbRoomType.DataSource = dt
                cmbRoomType.DisplayMember = "RoomNumber"
                cmbRoomType.ValueMember = "RoomID"
            End Using
        End Using
    End If

End Sub
```

Second option i can think of is to use another dropdown that is placed on same location that the first one
then instead of `If cmbRoomType.SelectedValue = Not vbNull` you can use

```
cmbRoomType.Visible = 0
cmbRoomType2.Visible = 1
```

Comment: Should i still keep the code for populating the comboboxes in the form Load?

Comment: Nope, you'd have to delete second part of code for this CB at form load.

Comment: an error occurs `: 'Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DataRowView' and type 'Integer'.'
`

Comment: which second part of the code shoul i delete both the Room Type and Room Number?

Comment: You leave Room Type, and delete RoomNumber from base load, Code to populate RoomNumber you put after event in another sub (Private Sub cmbRoomType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbRoomType.SelectedIndexChanged)

Comment: sorry to bother again however I asked another question on stack overflow about parent child comboboxes and I was wondering if you perhaps know how I can get the code from this [link](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?518065) to work with my comboboxes populated with my database tables. Kind regards

Comment: Still it would require two comboboxes to make it parent/child and you asked how to do it at all in one CB. That means it would still require event that checks for current selection. For user that implementation would be bad because user would have to click once, then choose, then unclick, then click at same CB again. IMO Jimmy there had brilliant idea, but you can do it the same for right SQL query that have relationships. 
Anyways read that https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?887311
You need to create bindings from creation menu, and link it to right dataset.